# Automount of CIFS share fails during boot while mount -a works after login

Tags: ssd, fstab, automount, cifs

I am trying to automatically mount a CIFS share on a Synology NAS during boot time. I am on a 14.04 LTS Workstation.

Everything works fine when I manually mount the share using the `fstab` entry, however, I have to repeat this step every time I am logged in.

I installed the `cifs-utils` and amended the `fstab` as follows:

```
//192.168.0.xxx/share /Volumes/share cifs iocharset=utf8,credentials=/var/xxx/.smb 0 0
```

.smb contains the username= and passwd= settings, different locations were tried.

The entry seems to work as I can either use `mount -a` or `mount /Volumes/share` to successfully mount the share.

Any ideas, why the automount during boot fails? So far I've tried various solutions including the _netdev option, which does however seem to break the entry.

TIA for your answers.

Comment: It could possibly be failing because the network isn't up by the time the cifs mount is attempted. You could try putting a script with `mount /Volumes/share` in an executable script in /etc/network/if-up.d so that it mounts after the network goes up.

Comment: just tried it, unfortunately no difference, the share is still not mounted upon boot

Comment: Hmm, [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NetworkManager#Use_dispatcher_to_handle_mounting_of_CIFS_shares) might help then. As a bonus, you can set it to only mount when connected to certain networks.

Answer (score 1):

thanks zhongfu, this was the path to the solution.

I had to change the arch-script to this to work:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$2" = "up" ]
   then
    mount /Volumes/share &
fi
```

location of the script:

```
/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/
```

Owner: root, mode 755

Now it works like a charm :-)

BTW: it could be related to my system booting off an SSD, the network actually is started after the login prompt is displayed

thanks again :-)